# How to get all the keys values from Redis Cache in C#?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a Redis cache, I have set a few keys in that, and now I need to get all the keys and their values. It seems that there is no direct method to get this.

I can see only `StringGet(string key)` method which takes a key as a parameter. But no method there for all the keys

**Edit:**

I have tied the below code, but it's giving an exception on 3rd line.

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();

var keys = redis.GetServer("localhost").Keys();

string[] keysArr = keys.Select(key => (string)key).ToArray();

foreach (string key in keysArr)
{
    Console.Write(db.StringGet(key));
}
```

**Exception:**

> the specified endpoint is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `Keys` method to get all the keys, remember you need to pass `allowAdmin=true"` in the `Connect` method.

```
using (ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379,allowAdmin=true"))
        {
            IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();

            var keys = redis.GetServer("localhost", 6379).Keys();

            string[] keysArr = keys.Select(key => (string)key).ToArray();

            foreach (string key in keysArr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(db.StringGet(key));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
IServer server = Connection.GetServer("yourcache.redis.cache.windows....", 6380);
foreach (var key in server.Keys())
{
   Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this code. its giving exception . the specified endpoint is not defined

Comment: could you explain, what is going on in the code, or you are just giving a try